# Creating a test or stage database from a production database in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I'm not sure how to create a database to use as a test/stage database from another database in Azure. It seems like the copy button in the Azure portal is gone from old tutorials I've read online.

I've created a database that will be used as the production db. Now I want to create another database that's exactly the same, and everyday at midnight I'd like to copy the production database tables, data, etc to the copy, so that's it's an exact copy, so that in the morning I can come in and work from the test/stage (copied) database and make changes (add data, delete data, change tables, etc) and then when ready update the production db.

Are there any good tutorial or additional ways to accomplish this?

What are the prescribes ways to do this?

Should I have some local copy on my machine or should I have two db's (prod, test) in Azure?

Any advice here would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to sync the data between production database and test/stage database every day.
Getting the data from the production db, and test in the test/stage db, then update to the production db again. Am I right?

Azure SQL database [Data Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-sync-data) can help you achieve that.

**Summary:**

Data Sync is useful in cases where data needs to be kept up-to-date across several Azure SQL databases or SQL Server databases. Here are the main use cases for Data Sync:

- **Hybrid Data Synchronization**: With Data Sync, you can keep data
  synchronized between your on-premises databases and Azure SQL
  databases to enable hybrid applications. This capability may appeal
  to customers who are considering moving to the cloud and would like
  to put some of their application in Azure.
- **Distributed Applications**: In many cases, it's beneficial to separate
  different workloads across different databases. For example, if you
  have a large production database, but you also need to run a
  reporting or analytics workload on this data, it's helpful to have a
  second database for this additional workload. This approach minimizes
  the performance impact on your production workload. You can use Data
  Sync to keep these two databases synchronized.
- **Globally Distributed Applications**: Many businesses span several
  regions and even several countries/regions. To minimize network
  latency, it's best to have your data in a region close to you. With
  Data Sync, you can easily keep databases in regions around the world
  synchronized.

The Data Sync supports the Sync Direction can be Hub to Member, or Member to Hub, or both.

You can create a database in Azure SQL database, and create an on-premise database with the same schema (for cost sake). Using the Azure SQL Database Data Sync to sync the data between the production db and on-premise db manual or automatic.

About how to create the Data Sync, please reference this official tutorial: [Tutorial: Set up SQL Data Sync between Azure SQL Database and SQL Server on-premises](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync)

Hope this hleps

Comment: Hi Leon. Thanks for the post, do you know if there's a way to copy just part of the prod data to dev? I'm just thinking ahead to when/if my prod db gets to multiple TB's in size, do I really want to have a copy of the entire db contents/data just for dev/testing?

Answer (score 0):

You can have two databases on Azure SQL Database. One will be your Production database and the other one your test/stage database. You can use [Azure Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-first-runbook-textual-powershell) and PowerShell to refresh (drop/create) your test/stage database whenever you want this to happen (every day, once a week, etc.)

1.Check if COPY database already exists - if so delete it

```
 Get-AzureRmSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ServerName $SqlServerName -DatabaseName $databaseCopyName
 Remove-AzureRmSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ServerName $SqlServerName
 -DatabaseName $databaseCopyName `
 -Force
```

2.Create COPY database

```
 New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseCopy -ResourceGroupName rg-resourcegroupname -ServerName sql-servername
 -Tags @{key="value"} -DatabaseName sqldb-databasename
 -CopyResourceGroupName rg-resourcegroupname -CopyServerName sql-servername
 -CopyDatabaseName sqldb-databasename-copy
```

Comment: what's the diff between this and data sync? and can i have one db (prod) in Azure and the second db (test) on a local machine?

Comment: With SQL Data Sync the database will be replicated to the test DB. My solution copies your production database to another database on Azure. Due to incompatibilities between SQL Server (local) and Azure SQL DB, you may want to consider having both databases in Azure instead.

Comment: I currently will host all db's in Azure - prod, dev, QA, etc. So what's the difference between copy and replicate. I've currently copied my prod db to use as my test/dev db and then synced it with prod (hub) on a schedule ex. 1/day. This is done in Azure.  Isn;'t this the same as your solution, but less cumbersome?

Comment: @user1186050 Not the same. Your configuration needs both databases to have the same service tier. You also get a new schema added in your database (dss) to keep track of changes and that has an impacton your database. When you copy the database you can set the database Azure Serverless, it will get paused when not in used and you will pay by minute instead by hour.

Comment: Do you have any docs or link that you can provide to show me what this is, I'm having a hard time understanding what you're suggesting? FYI - I'm doing everything in the Azure portal. I'm doing an Azure copy, which seems like it's what you're suggesting above, but then I just take it one step farther and sync to the prod(hub) db to get all the data?

Comment: Once you copy the database, drop the test/dev database, then rename the copied database to the name of the test/dev database you just dropped. In addition you can use Azure SQL Data Sync to keep 2 databases in sync https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-data-sync-sql-server-configure?view=azuresql